# AzerothCore Intial Install Schema Missing

Tags: azerothcore

I am standing up a fresh install on Ubuntu 20 LTS.  Following the standard install doc.  Looks like it isn't working as expected.

Server.log

```
AzerothCore rev. 55d17c1c538d 2021-11-18 14:48:31 -0300 (master branch) (Unix, RelWithDebInfo, Static) (worldserver-daemon)
<Ctrl-C> to stop.

   █████╗ ███████╗███████╗██████╗  ██████╗ ████████╗██╗  ██╗
  ██╔══██╗╚══███╔╝██╔════╝██╔══██╗██╔═══██╗╚══██╔══╝██║  ██║
  ███████║  ███╔╝ █████╗  ██████╔╝██║   ██║   ██║   ███████║
  ██╔══██║ ███╔╝  ██╔══╝  ██╔══██╗██║   ██║   ██║   ██╔══██║
  ██║  ██║███████╗███████╗██║  ██║╚██████╔╝   ██║   ██║  ██║
  ╚═╝  ╚═╝╚══════╝╚══════╝╚═╝  ╚═╝ ╚═════╝    ╚═╝   ╚═╝  ╚═╝
                                 ██████╗ ██████╗ ██████╗ ███████╗
                                ██╔════╝██╔═══██╗██╔══██╗██╔════╝
                                ██║     ██║   ██║██████╔╝█████╗
                                ██║     ██║   ██║██╔══██╗██╔══╝
                                ╚██████╗╚██████╔╝██║  ██║███████╗
                                 ╚═════╝ ╚═════╝ ╚═╝  ╚═╝╚══════╝

     AzerothCore 3.3.5a  -  www.azerothcore.org

> Using configuration file       /home/wow/azeroth-server/etc/worldserver.conf
> Using SSL version:             OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020 (library: OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020)
> Using Boost version:           1.71.0

Process priority class set to -15
Initializing Scripts...
> Loading C++ scripts

Opening DatabasePool 'acore_characters'. Asynchronous connections: 1, synchronous connections: 1.
DatabasePool 'acore_characters' opened successfully. 2 total connections running.

Opening DatabasePool 'acore_characters'. Asynchronous connections: 1, synchronous connections: 2.
DatabasePool 'acore_characters' opened successfully. 3 total connections running.

Opening DatabasePool 'acore_world'. Asynchronous connections: 1, synchronous connections: 1.
DatabasePool 'acore_world' opened successfully. 2 total connections running.

Updating Auth database...
>> Auth database is up-to-date! Containing 2 new and 26 archived updates.

Updating Character database...
>> Character database is up-to-date! Containing 2 new and 26 archived updates.

Updating World database...
>> World database is up-to-date! Containing 192 new and 2008 archived updates.

Closing down DatabasePool 'acore_characters'.
Asynchronous connections on DatabasePool 'acore_characters' terminated. Proceeding with synchronous connections.
All connections on DatabasePool 'acore_characters' closed.
Could not prepare statements of the Character database, see log for details.
Closing down DatabasePool 'acore_world'.
Asynchronous connections on DatabasePool 'acore_world' terminated. Proceeding with synchronous connections.
All connections on DatabasePool 'acore_world' closed.
Closing down DatabasePool 'acore_characters'.
Asynchronous connections on DatabasePool 'acore_characters' terminated. Proceeding with synchronous connections.
All connections on DatabasePool 'acore_characters' closed.
Closing down DatabasePool 'acore_characters'.
Asynchronous connections on DatabasePool 'acore_characters' terminated. Proceeding with synchronous connections.
All connections on DatabasePool 'acore_characters' closed.
```

In the DBerrors.log it trys to delete/update/change tables that don't currently exist on acore_characters.  Here is all that exist on acore_characters.

```
+----------------------------+
| Tables_in_acore_characters |
+----------------------------+
| account                    |
| account_access             |
| account_banned             |
| account_muted              |
| autobroadcast              |
| build_info                 |
| ip_banned                  |
| logs                       |
| logs_ip_actions            |
| realmcharacters            |
| realmlist                  |
| secret_digest              |
| updates                    |
| updates_include            |
| uptime                     |
| version_db_auth            |
+----------------------------+
```

Maybe the autoupdater isn't populating this?

Some truncated examples of the DBerrors.log

```
In mysql_stmt_prepare() id: 0, sql: "DELETE FROM pool_quest_save WHERE pool_id = ?"
Table 'acore_characters.pool_quest_save' doesn't exist
In mysql_stmt_prepare() id: 1, sql: "INSERT INTO pool_quest_save (pool_id, quest_id) VALUES (?, ?)"
Table 'acore_characters.pool_quest_save' doesn't exist
In mysql_stmt_prepare() id: 2, sql: "DELETE FROM guild_bank_item WHERE guildid = ? AND TabId = ? AND SlotId = ?"
Table 'acore_characters.guild_bank_item' doesn't exist
In mysql_stmt_prepare() id: 3, sql: "UPDATE character_banned SET active = 0 WHERE unbandate <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP() AND unbandate <> bandate"
Table 'acore_characters.character_banned' doesn't exist
In mysql_stmt_prepare() id: 4, sql: "SELECT guid, account, name, gender, race, class, level FROM characters WHERE deleteDate IS NULL AND name = ?"
Table 'acore_characters.characters' doesn't exist
In mysql_stmt_prepare() id: 5, sql: "SELECT guid, account, name, gender, race, class, level FROM characters WHERE deleteDate IS NULL AND guid = ?"
Table 'acore_characters.characters' doesn't exist
In mysql_stmt_prepare() id: 6, sql: "SELECT 1 FROM characters WHERE name = ?"
Table 'acore_characters.characters' doesn't exist
In mysql_stmt_prepare() id: 8, sql: "SELECT COUNT(guid) FROM characters WHERE account = ?"
Table 'acore_characters.characters' doesn't exist
In mysql_stmt_prepare() id: 9, sql: "SELECT level, race, class FROM characters WHERE account = ? LIMIT 0, ?"
Table 'acore_characters.characters' doesn't exist
```

Attempted running an update...

```
root@ubuntu:/home/wow/azerothcore# bash /home/wow/azerothcore/apps/db_assembler/db_assembler.sh
NOTICE: file </home/wow/azerothcore/conf/config.sh> has not been found, you should create and configure it.
Deno version check:
Checking https://github.com/denoland/deno/releases/download/v1.9.1/deno-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.zip
30.1 MiB / 30.1 MiB (100.0%)
Deno is upgrading to version 1.9.1
Archive:  /tmp/.tmpPvQ6U1/deno.zip
  inflating: deno
Upgraded successfully
1) all: Assemble all                                4) customs: Assemble only customs                   7) import-updates: Assemble & Import only updates
2) bases: Assemble only bases                       5) import-all: Assemble & Import all                8) import-customs:  Assemble & Import only customs
3) updates: Assemble only updates                   6) import-bases: Assemble & Import only bases       9) quit: Exit from this menu
[Please enter your choice]: 7
=====     DB ASSEMBLER MENU     =====
===== STARTING ASSEMBLY PROCESS =====
Generating /home/wow/azerothcore/env/dist/sql/auth_updates ...
Searching on /home/wow/azerothcore/data/sql/updates/db_auth/ ...
Searching on /home/wow/azerothcore/data/sql/updates/pending_db_auth/ ...
Generating /home/wow/azerothcore/env/dist/sql/characters_updates ...
Searching on /home/wow/azerothcore/data/sql/updates/db_characters/ ...
Searching on /home/wow/azerothcore/data/sql/updates/pending_db_characters/ ...
Generating /home/wow/azerothcore/env/dist/sql/world_updates ...
Searching on /home/wow/azerothcore/data/sql/updates/db_world/ ...
Searching on /home/wow/azerothcore/data/sql/updates/pending_db_world/ ...
=====           DONE            =====
=====       CHECKING DBs        =====
mysqld is alive
acore_auth database exists
mysqld is alive
acore_characters database exists
mysqld is alive
acore_world database exists
=====           DONE            =====
===== STARTING IMPORTING PROCESS =====
importing AUTH - updates ...
mysqld is alive
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 4: Table 'acore_auth.updates' doesn't exist
```

Oh wow yeah alot of acore_chatacters tables are missing... https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/database-characters

I went back and dropped all databases and recreated then ran `bash /home/wow/azerothcore/apps/db_assembler/db_assembler.sh` Option 5 to import everything manually before start.  Same result except there are a lot more tables now in acore_characters schema.  Smaller amount is mising.

I have tried allowing the auth and world bin's to populate the DB.  When using the auto-db method auth works just fine but acore_characters is not fully populated.  When I use the old assembler method auth won't start, stating that tables are missing from the schema.  However acore_characters has a ton more tables.  Right now neither method seems to propely and completly populate the acore_characters database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out is was MariaDB, use MySQL instead.  The wiki says either works but I imgaine a change in Ubuntu 20 LTS mariadb is incompatable with AzerothCore.

Comment: this is not true, it should work with MariaDB too

Comment: Fair, just reporting what I found. mariadb-server-10.5/stable,now 1:10.5.12-0+deb11u1 works, while mariadb-server/focal-updates,focal-security 1:10.3.31-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 does not.  They are different OS's so other delta's could definately exist, but nothing that easily stood out.

Comment: that's worth a bug report then, because AC should support MariaDB too: https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/blob/master/.github/SECURITY.md